# Git - Remote Head not updating properly

Tags: git

I'm facing a weird issue with git. My pushes to a remote git repository is not happening as expected. When I do a push to the remote repository, only the changes in the push  that was done just before the latest push are reflected in the remote repository. I suspect that my remote's HEAD is not pointing to the latest commit. Instead, it points to the the previous push and hence the anomaly. The following is my branch list.

```
(ENV)machine:~/Production-git/XXXX_tool$ git branch -a
 * master
   remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
   remotes/origin/master
```

I don't understand what the above represents.

I'm pretty sure that when I push the changes, it is actually updating the the remote repository(since when i do a 'git diff origin master', it doesn't show any difference). But since the Head lags by one push, when I clone the repository, I don't get the latest changes.

It would be great if anyone could help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do with initially like how you start the git.

> git init

but i know that is not the solution ...

try below commands for updating remote `head`

> git remote set-head $REMOTE_NAME $BRANCH

like that `git remote set-head origin develop`

Comment: The second command is what I was looking for. I have reset the head for the remote branch and now it works like a charm!