# Files in a git remote repository are not updated properly

Tags: git

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Y8x.png)

Background: We have an instruction to create a remote repository in a shared drive (in this case, OneDrive) instead of creating a remote repository in Github. Then, we would be cloning this remote repository in our local machines. There are no conflicts when we push our changes and the `git log` result is updated correctly on both local and remote repositories.

Problem: The files in the remote repository are still in their previous versions. For example, if I make a commit and push *third commit*, the remote repository receives *third commit* but the files are still in version *second commit* and the changes in *third commit* are logged as a staged changes.

Workaround #1: The developer who made the latest commit must go to the remote repository and manually update the files by executing the following commands:

```
git restore --staged .
git restore .
```

Workaround #2: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541999/git-remote-head-not-updating-properly) does not work.

Expected Result: After developer pushes their changes, remote repository must automatically update the files based on the latest changes. No workaround needed.

How can we achieve the expected result? Please help. TIA.

Comment: `git push` sends to the remote repository the missing commits and updates the branches, except for the currently checked out branch. It does not affect the working tree(s) of the remote repository. It cannot do that on purpose, to not loose work and create confusion. Think what happens if the remote repository is the working repository of one of your coworkers.

Comment: You know that the repositories on Github are bare repositories, don't you? A bare repository does not have a working tree attached. Are you sure that the requirement is to create a regular repository on OneDrive and not a bare repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps setting the config option `receive.denyCurrentBranch=updateInstead` will do what you want.